# Regular expression: match all words except 8-digit sequences

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string like `"hello, dflk 1234 12345678, wod-=0, 87654321"` and I would like to get a list of all "words", which do not correspond to regular expression pattern `"\d{8}"` (eight digits in a row).

I studied java.util.regex [api doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html), however I was unable to find a way to put together  **negation of regular expression "\d{8}"**. Here's the way I would like to use it:

```
String input = "hello, dflk 1234 12345678, wod-=0, 87654321";
List<String> hitList = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(...?...); //<- how to define the regex pattern?
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    hitList.add(m.group());
}
```

I'd like to have all of these in my hitList (based on the input string above):

```
"hello,"  "dflk"  "1234"  ","  "wod-=0,"
```

Can you suggest a way to define that regex pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (that's probably the easiest) is to filter the resulting list of matches.

Another would be a negative lookahead and a few more lookarounds:

```
(?<=^|\s|\d{8})(?!\d{8})\S+(?=$|\s|\d{8})
```

Pretty is different, I think.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:\> [regex]::Matches('hello, dflk 1234 12345678, wod-=0, 87654321', '(?<=^|\s|\d{8})(?!\d{8})\S+(?=$|\s|\d{8})')|
select -exp Value
hello,
dflk
1234
,
wod-=0,
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used replaced your source string where the pattern is found with empty string and then used String split function to get all strings other than the pattern

```
String test = "hello, dflk 1234 12345678, wod-=0, 87654321";
            test = test.replaceAll("\\d{8}", "");
            String result[] = test.split("\\ ");
            for (String value : result) {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
```

I have tested the above solution.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the regex you're looking for (remember that you need to escape the \ when putting it in a string):

```
(?<!\s)(?!\d{8}(\s|$))\S+
```